# Парсинг текста со страницы и передача в List C#

Tags: c#, list

Здравствуйте, такая вот проблема

Мне надо спарсить прокси со страницы, а затем передать их в List.

```
public static List<string> ProxyList = new List<string>();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но у меня вот такая ошибка.

Сам код парсинга прокси:

```
 string URLProxy = client.DownloadString("http://awmproxy.com/freeproxy_2356428077.txt?");
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне это нормально реализовать?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно разбить полученные данные на строки (метод [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)) и добавить их в список (метод [AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
ProxyList.AddRange(URLProxy.Split());
```

Comment: Большое спасибо :)
Делал тоже самое, только вот Split не добавлял. )